# How to avoid memory leaks when building a slice of slices using ArrayLists

Tags: memory-leaks, zig

I'm trying to build a slice of slices using multiple `std.ArrayList`s.

The code below works, but the memory allocator `std.testing.allocator` warns me of a memory leaks wherever I append new elements to a `sublist`.

```zig
const std = @import("std");
const mem = std.mem;

fn sliceOfSlices(allocator: *mem.Allocator) ![][]usize {
    var list = std.ArrayList([]usize).init(allocator);

    var i: usize = 0;
    while (i < 3) : (i += 1) {
        var sublist = std.ArrayList(usize).init(allocator);
        // errdefer sublist.deinit(); // here?
        var n: usize = 0;
        while (n < 5) : (n += 1) {
            try sublist.append(n); // leaks
            // errdefer sublist.deinit(); // here?
            // errdefer allocator.free(sublist.items);
        }
        try list.append(sublist.toOwnedSlice());
    }
    return list.toOwnedSlice();
}

const testing = std.testing;

test "memory leaks" {
    const slice = try sliceOfSlices(testing.allocator);
    testing.expectEqual(@intCast(usize, 3), slice.len);
    testing.expectEqual(@intCast(usize, 5), slice[0].len);
}
```

I tried to use `errdefer` in several places to free the allocated `sublist`, but it didn't work. From the documentation it seems a lifetime issue, but I'm not sure how to handle it.

> the std.ArrayList(T).items slice has a lifetime that remains valid until the next time the list is resized, such as by appending new elements.
> — https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/#Lifetime-and-Ownership

What's the appropriate error handling when `list.append()` fails?

Answer (score 3):

I am a beginner to zig so perhaps I am totally wrong here, but I think the reason why you are getting the memory leak is **not** because something failed!

As you use `ArrayList` its memory is allocated via an allocator, the memory has explicitly to be freed at end of usage. For an `ArrayList` you could simply use the `deinit()` function. However as your function `sliceOfSlices()` converts that `ArrayList` wrapper to a slice, you have to use `testing.allocator.free(slice)` to get rid of the memory used by that slice.

**But note:** every element of your slice is itself a slice (or a pointer to it). Also obtained via `ArrayList.toOwnedSlice()`. Therefore those slices you have also to get rid of, before you can deallocate the containing slice.

So I would change your test to

```zig
test "memory leaks" {
    const slice = try sliceOfSlices(testing.allocator);
    defer {
        for (slice) |v| {
            testing.allocator.free(v);
        }
        testing.allocator.free(slice);
    }
    testing.expectEqual(@intCast(usize, 3), slice.len);
    testing.expectEqual(@intCast(usize, 5), slice[0].len);
}
```

and now no memory leak should occur anymore.

Perhaps somebody knows a better solution, but lacking experience here, this would be the way to go, IMO.

And after some thinking, answering your question what to do in case of an error, I would rewrite your function `sliceOfSlices()` to

```zig
fn sliceOfSlices(allocator: *mem.Allocator) ![][]usize {
    var list = std.ArrayList([]usize).init(allocator);
    errdefer {
        for (list.items) |slice| {
            allocator.free(slice);
        }
        list.deinit();
    }

    var i: usize = 0;
    while (i < 3) : (i += 1) {
        var sublist = std.ArrayList(usize).init(allocator);
        errdefer sublist.deinit();

        var n: usize = 0;
        while (n < 5) : (n += 1) {
            try sublist.append(n);
        }

        try list.append(sublist.toOwnedSlice());
    }

    return list.toOwnedSlice();
}
```

Now if any error happened in your function, both `list` and `sublist` should be cleaned up properly. Still if no error was returned from the function, your calling code would be responsible for the cleanup to avoid memory leaks like implemented in the `test` block above.